# What is the cheapest way to get from Central Europe to South East Asia between Christmas and the New Year?

Tags: air-travel, budget, thailand, southeast-asia, central-europe

My final destination is Thailand.

Since rail is relatively cheap between SE Asian countries, I am not too concerned about where I initially land down there.

Most direct flights to Bangkok for example are $1500 USD / $1200 EUR, I am looking to pay at least 300-400 EUR less.

Comment: Cheapest might be hitch-hiking, but you won't make it between Christmas and New-Year, it'll take longer (;

Comment: Thai Air direct flight 783€ from Frankfurt. via Taipeh 498€ one way. Is it return you're talking about?

Comment: This question will be a helped a lot by how long you plan to stay and where your closest airport is.

Comment: How long is the trip allowed to be would also be good to know, would it be ok to travel 2-3 days to get to Bangkok? Going to northern europe and then flying over the north pole to China might take some time, but some great deals. Might also look in to flying to Singapore or Kuala Lumpur then taking a bus or three. From Stockholm to BKK there are often very good deals, last week I saw a early christmas flight for ~230€ one way.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, there are experts available on crowd-sourced flight search enginers like Flightfox.com (see [my profile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) for a discount link).

On there, you can say, ask for a flight from Central Europe to Thailand/Cambodia etc (there was a flight last week on there from San Francisco to "anywhere"!), and all the dates criteria you like, and have people search for you.

Yes it costs, but if they can't beat your price, you get your money back.  And so far, for me, they've always saved me money.

(Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated, but I do compete on there to find the best prices, and have met the founders)